# JQuery .each just gets the first two elements from array of auto generated elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, playframework

I have a for loop which generates me a few `divs` with the class `panel`.

```
@for(comment <- event.getCommentsSorted()) {
```

Now I want to change every `div` with jQuery but `.each` just gets the first two `divs` with the class `panel`.

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
        $(".panel").each(function (index) {
            alert(index);
            $(this).height($(this)[index].scrollHeight - 12);
        });
    });
```

The other three divs are just not there.

[image]

I thought maybe it's because the script is executed before all the `divs` are generated but with `load` the script should execute after pageload.
I also tried it with `.ready` or with a different number of generated `divs` but it doesn't matter I just get the first two elements.

So why I get just the fist two elements, and is there a way to get all elements?

Comment: Sounds like others are being added by script after page loads

Comment: I think your for loop is running after the page load. try to add some console message/alert in for loop as well and find the execution sequence.

Comment: Sounds like a job for event delegation. How exactly are your elements getting added?

Comment: I'll try it with an allert in the loop. The divs are added directly in the loop. First I have a check if in the database are comments(divs) to generate. If yes the loop iterates over all comments and inserts them into a form in each .panel div.

Comment: It seems that the comments are loaded before the script is executed... so maybe it's something with the scrollHeight...

Comment: The [`.ready`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) event is correct. To be 100% sure which divs are sent from the server use your browser developer tools and look at the response body.

Comment: All divs are sent, the pic is from the developer console in the browser..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Answer, it seems that

```
$(this).height($(this)[index].scrollHeight
```

just doesn't work.

I have no idea why, but with this everything works fine.

```
$(".panel .inputSizeLimitation").each(function () {
       $(this).height($(this).prop("scrollHeight") - 12);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap the call to `.each` inside a `setTimeout` for example:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".panel").each(function (index) {
      alert(index);
      $(this).height($(this)[index].scrollHeight - 12);
    });
  }, 3000); // wait 3 seconds before executing
});
```

Comment: Good idea, thank you, but then the time depends on how many divs are loaded... which is not so good.